# XPath to elements in "ol" but not in sub-"ol"

Tags: xpath

(Solution found!)

Consider the following html structure (simplified from the [page](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/sittings/1900/jan/30) I am struggling with).

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class=page>
    <ol class="xoxo first">
      <li class="selection-line>
        Item 1
      <li class="selection-line>
        Item 2
        <ol class="xoxo">
          <li class="selection-line>
            Item 3
          <li class="selection-line>
            Item 4
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to select items 1 and 2, but *not* 3 and 4.

Upon completing this post I checked the code and found a silly mistake. It is working now, but I will post nonetheless in case someone else has the same question.

Solution:

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "section-line", " " )) and not(ancestor::*[@class = 'xoxo'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon completing this post I checked the code and found a silly mistake. It is working now, but I will post nonetheless in case someone else has the same question.

```
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "section-line", " " )) and not(ancestor::*[@class = 'xoxo'])]
```